# Linux audio mixer DAW

Tags: music, music-production

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 and 1.6 GB of loops. I want a DAW where I can place these tracks and create mashup-style tracks from these sounds? What could I install?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Audacity](http://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/): the GUI is quite austere but it is a good start.

Comment: I already use Audacity until I can find something better.